# How can I make my div's svg background image scale dynamically and stay in the center of the div

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm currently working on the following website design:

[image]

I have two sections (top and bottom) that are both divided into two sections (icon and content). I'm trying to use a centered svg image in the icon section although the image gets cut off whenever the size of the viewing area/browser window changes. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is what I am currently using:

Example - [js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dgfsq6k5/)

SVG Image - [svg image](http://eatmyrice.org/065__calendar.svg)

HTML -

```
<div id="main1">
   <div id="icon1">&#160;</div>​ 
   <div id="links1">
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
   </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="main2">
   <div id="icon2">​​​</div>
   <div id="links2">
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" contenteditable="false">
   <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read a64b9522-0ca6-4ff7-a9fc-67a7a27d3071" id="div_a64b9522-0ca6-4ff7-a9fc-67a7a27d3071" unselectable="on">
   </div>
   <div id="vid_a64b9522-0ca6-4ff7-a9fc-67a7a27d3071" unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
<style>
#main1 > div { min-height: 100px; }
#main1 {
    /* overflow to handle inner floating block */
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 20px; 
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

#icon1 {
    float: left;
    width: 29%;
    border-right:thin solid red;
}

#links1 {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}
#main2 > div { min-height: 100px; }
#main2 {
    /* overflow to handle inner floating block */
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 20px; 
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

#icon2 {
    float: left;
    width: 29%;
    border-right:thin solid red;
    /* background: url('/support/Shared%20Documents/065__calendar.svg') no-repeat center; */
    background-image: url('/support/Shared%20Documents/065__calendar_crop.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#links2 {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: how about an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Quoid here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/dgfsq6k5/. The actual environment that I would be using this for is in sharepoint, but I'm not able to give access to it (the server is configured to not allow internet access), so this is as close of an example as I can get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-size: contain` instead of `cover` and use `background-position: center center` to keep it centered.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dgfsq6k5/3/)**

Review the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) from W3schools:

> **Cover**
>
> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. **Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area**
>
> **Contain**
>
> Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area